# Search name using jQuery autocomplete, after pressing enter - select RadioButton

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, radio-button

I am writing an application in asp.NET, I use the MVC 3 model(views engine Razor). I have no idea how to do that after searching for a suitable name in jQuery autocomplete and pressing Enter on the name, application will check appropiate RadioButton.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {                       
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: "/Home/TakeGry",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {
            // I suspect that something needs to add here  
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <div class="demo">
                <div class="ui-widget">
                    <label for="tags">Surowce: </label>
                    <input id="tags" />
                    <input id="hiddenElementID" type="hidden" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>

        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nazwa)
        </td>
        <td>
            // One of these RadioButton's should be checked, when I hit enter
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.GraID, new { id = item.GraID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of searching, I found the answer, which I put below:

I must change my script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: "/Home/TakeGry",
        minLength: 0,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                $('input[name="' +ui.item.value+ '"]').attr('checked', true);                    
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And in foreach ( which print names and RadioButtons ) i must change that:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.GraID, new { id = item.GraID })
```

To:

```
<input type="radio" name='@item.Nazwa' id="radioButton" value="{ id = @item.GraID }" />
```

Thanks for any help :).

Answer (score 0):

the function only requires a collection of strings.
you can do a manual post which gets a space separated string and then split that on space to an array and pass it to the function:

```
$(function () {
    var list;
    $.post("/Home/TakeGry", { }, function(result) {
        list = result.split(' ');
    });


    $("#tags").autocomplete(list);
});
```

Comment: My jQuery autocomplete function work fine, but when I select something from autocomplete list, appropiate RadioButton must be auto-selected. I don't know how to do asynchronously, without reloading the page.

Comment: ok, i think you should be able to do it with help from this eventhandler:
[link](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result#handler)